# auth tank 1.0.7

Tags: codeigniter

Recently they just went to 1.0.8 for the new codeigniter 2.0 release. I still use codeigniter 1.7.3 and now finding auth tank 1.0.8 doesnt work for it. I tried looking for version history on auth tanks website but couldn't . Any one know where i can get auth tank 1.0.7?

Comment: something tells me TankAuth would be way more popular if they had named it "Auth Tank!!!"

Comment: What doesn't work? If I recall I was using TankAuth with CI2.0 and I had to make a couple of tweaks to the code. If I recall it was due to some security function being removed from CIs `input` class. If you can provide specific information I could dig up the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the SVN repository here and using your SVN client (Tortoise SVN or whatever) go back in revisions and versions to 1.0.7. Here is the repo: https://tankauth.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/tankauth/ - although, what issues are you having with 1.0.8 anyway? What are the error messages you are getting?

The issue is most likely to do with the fact that CI 2 introduced changes to how controllers and models are extended. In CI 1.7.2 / 1.7.3 controllers and models extended Controller and Model respetively, however in CI 2 controllers extend CI_Controller and models extend CI_Model.

Maybe go through the code and make sure that Tank Auth is extending the latter and not the CI_ prefixed controllers and models.

Also in CI 2 your models and controllers now call the parent class via parent::__construct(), however in CI 1.7.x your contructor functions called the parent class like this: parent::Controller() and parent::Model().

I think besides those two dramatic changes, not much else changed in the way of dramatic changes between the version jump.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and now it's solved.

generaly if you want the version history on Sourceforge simply go to Code -> SVN Browse tab and select the needed history version for download.

or for your specific need go to http://tankauth.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tankauth/?pathrev=18
this this tankauth version is the last version before making it compatible with Codeigniter 2.
I have tested this version on Codeigniter 1.7.2 and it worked!